# Iam trying to get image from assets directory but once i build the project the assets directory changed

Tags: angular

In the code i have `<img style="width: 40%;" src="/assets/images/user.png" alt="image">` and its work great when I run it locally. once I build it and deploy it to the server it returns error 404 for this image.
the files run at {my domain}/manage.

any ideas?

Comment: update `src="/assets/images/user.png"` to `src="assets/images/user.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your assets folder is packed along with your application.
load you appication hit F12 and go to source and check whether assets folder is there or not.

If it is not there then you will get 404 not found error in your console

Comment: I cant see the assets folder in the Sources but it is in the same directory...

Comment: try uploading your assets folder also in the root folder of the server it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img style="width: 40%;" src="assets/images/user.png" alt="image">
```

Make sure the image is in images folder and its type is png as mentioned.

Also make sure assets folder is added in your angular.json.

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

Comment: `"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],`
this one in as it look ln my project 
and `<img style="width: 40%;" src="assets/images/user.png" alt="image">`
this one change nothing